# Get portion of a table and get 2 tables 1 being updated SQL Server

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table like:

```
id NameColumn 
-------------
1  var
2  var2 
3  var3
4  var4
5  var5
...  ...
n  varn
```

Is there a Way I can get a portion of this table, say, the first 3, and get to tables (the second one in the field 'id' is updated) like:

TABLE1:

```
id NameColumn 
-------------
1  var
2  var2 
3  var3
```

TABLE2:

```
id NameColumn 
-------------
1  var4
2  var5
3  var6
4  var7
...  ...
n  varn
```

Comment: Are you looking for a Query/View? Or do you wish to create a new table with Identity starting at 1?

Comment: create a new table with Identity starting at 1, getting 2 tables, updating the first and creating the second

Comment: OK, so you wish to create a second table, and move certain items from the first to the second. Are there any specific criteria that would detemine which rows should be moved?

Comment: Exactly what you described, the criterio will be  a specific number, lets say 10, and only ten rows are kept, the other will be moved to other table, begining with id 1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at this example script. Is this what you had in mind?

```
DECLARE @Table1 TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY,
        Name VARCHAR(20)
)
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE(
        ID INT IDENTITY,
        Name VARCHAR(20)
)
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Name) SELECT 'A'
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Name) SELECT 'B'
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Name) SELECT 'C'
INSERT INTO @Table1 (Name) SELECT 'D'

DECLARE @N INT
SELECT  @N = 2

INSERT INTO @Table2
SELECT  Name
FROM    @Table1 t1 
WHERE   ID NOT IN   (
                        SELECT  TOP (@N)
                                ID
                        FROM    @Table1 
                        ORDER BY    ID
                    )
DELETE FROM @Table1
WHERE   ID NOT IN   (
                    SELECT  TOP (@N)
                            ID
                    FROM    @Table1 
                    ORDER BY    ID
                )

SELECT  *
FROM    @Table1
SELECT  *
FROM    @Table2
```

Comment: Yes thats exactly what I was looking for!!

Answer (score 0):

Try this..

TABLE1:

```
SELECT TOP 3 *
  FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
ORDER BY ID
```

TABLE2:

```
SELECT *
  FROM ( 
        SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS ID, 
               NameColumn
          FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
       )
```

To insert into new table try:

```
INSERT INTO <YOUR_NEW_TABLE>
    SELECT *
      FROM ( 
            SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY ID) AS ID, 
                   NameColumn
              FROM <YOUR_TABLE>
           )
```

Comment: How would I change that query , so it inserts the rows into other table?